# visa refusal from Spain in Nigeria

Tags: visa-refusals, spain, nigerian-citizens

[image][image]I applied with my colleagues 7 of us for a buisness visa to Spain invited by my company but only mine was refused. Earlier this year my France tourist visa was rejected could it be the reason.

The only Reason they gave is. Justification of trip not reliable. Help. The Trip is in 2 months can I reapply again with a cover letter this time explaining my visit and intentions with an Itenary. I have a fully booked fight to and fro and accommodation paid by my company

Comment: Did you do anything differently in the Spain application to address the French refusal reason(s)? For example, provide better financial paperwork, a more convincing reason for the trip, compelling evidence of ties to Nigeria? If you basically submitted pretty much the same application/paperwork to Spain as you did for France, the outcome was very probably a foregone conclusion.

Comment: Perhaps you can discuss with your colleagues what their justification of the trip was, to see what your application may be lacking. You say the France visa was rejected, but that was for a tourist visa, so was it  rejected for a different reason?

Comment: @WeatherVane the France Visa was rejected for the same reason. I checked with my colleagues and found one or two differences along the line of proof of address, they added their utility bill that shows their address. 

My company is planning to mail the embassy and they also advised that I request an appeal to the mail also adding the Invite letters of all my colleagues as it’s same with mine and also their visa approval. 

Is this a good Idea because I really want to go for the team retreat. Thanks

Comment: I don't get it: why do you need justification for a tourist visa besides "because I want to see France"? A business visa has different requirements. There must be something you aren't saying. Please show the relevant parts of both refusal letters (with personal details redacted).

Comment: Is a "team retreat" actually a "business visit"?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes a team retreat and a buisness  Visa. I have added the letters to the post

Comment: @WeatherVane I found the issue with my Visa application. In my introduction letter I wrote team retreat my colleagues wrote team Internal meeting. You are a blessing. It was an oversight on my end, our invitation actually stated team Internal meeting. Can I appeal this. I have all the evidences and my company is willing to support me?

Comment: The French refusal indicates that you didn't supply any details at all, and that they doubt you will leave.

Comment: Hello @WeatherVane can you advise if an appeal is appropriate or a reapplication is advisable in this regard?